# Solution for server side web scraping/navigation (with JavaScript support)

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I need to do server side web scraping/navigation, including sites with JavaScript, and I need a solution that would work on a hosting plan - I dont have my own server.
I came across python/pyside/pyqt4 - this would work perfectly/allow me to navigate sites like a headless browser. However I don't know if this would be possible to install on a remote server/host...

Answer (score 2):

If you need a headless browser, you should check out [PhantomJS](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/), and in particular PyPhantomJS, the Python implementation. These *might* work in a shared hosting context - it really depends on the host. See the [build instructions for different platforms](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/BuildInstructions) - you'd likely need to ask your hosting provider to install.

If you can get this running, you might be interested in checking out [pjscrape](http://nrabinowitz.github.com/pjscrape/) (disclaimer: this is my project). It's a command-line tool using PhantomJS to allow scraping using JavaScript and jQuery in a full browser context.

Comment: Do you know if there might be any solutions that are implemented in python or ruby or php... Something I could just upload to my hosting space?

Comment: Also I think HTMLUnitwould probably do the job well... This is in java... do you know of any web hosts with java support?

Comment: Also, how does your pyscrape work client side if the same origin policy prevents JavaScript on one domain from accessing data on another?

Comment: 1) PyPhantomJS is implemented in Python, as I noted in my answer. It involves Webkit, though, so I don't know if installation would be as simple as uploading it. 2) Pjscrape runs through PhantomJS, so it's not really "client-side" - it injects JS into the current page context.